# Form email randomly not sending Sitecore 9.3

Tags: sitecore-forms

Recently a user noted that a form was randomly not sending emails. Out of the last 22 submissions, they received 20.

- Form data is being saved to Sitecore db
- SMTP logs have no issues on Sitecore server
- Checked with outlook admin on recipient side, there were no delivery attempts to recipient
- Form data has doesn't appear to have input that might potentially trigger a spam filter

Are there any troubleshooting tips that I might've missed, or has anyone run across this before? Appreciate any insight

Comment: Are you using exchange server you might check the filter or log in details for failed emails it gives more details there if your form is using external smtp in Sitecore @eKoz